# Hide plaintext password from showing in bash script?

Tags: linux, bash

I have the following `bash` script to restart the *network manager* in Debian. The script works as is it should, but not as I would like it to. When the script asks for the `sudo` password I am able to pass it along using `echo`, but it displays the password in terminal while the script executes, making it less  asthetically pleasing than I would like. Is there anyway to have the script enter the password, but not display the password text while the script calls for the `sudo` password?

I have tried as many suggestions on *Stack Overflow* as i could find, well as *Stack Exchange* before submitting this question.

Script is as follows:

```
#!/bin/bash 
clear
echo "Restarting service Network Manager"
echo""
sleep 1
echo -e "\033[0;31m......................................\033[0m"
echo -e "\033[0;31m......................................\033[0m"
sleep 1
echo""  
sudo service network-manager restart
sleep 2
echo <Password> 
sleep 2
echo "Service Network Manager Restarted"
sleep 1
echo "" 
echo "Relinquishing control of terminal to user..."
sleep 7
clear
```

Comment: [Prompt for sudo password and programmatically elevate privilege in bash script?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/28791/56041), [How to enter password only once in a bash script needing sudo](https://askubuntu.com/q/711580), [Use sudo without password INSIDE a script](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25215604/608639), etc.

Answer (score 3):

Remove the `echo <Password>` line? I am pretty sure it does nothing other than display the password, as `sudo` apparently (through an appropriate entry in `/etc/sudoers`) works without you having to *give* a password. (What you write to terminal with `echo` does *not* get passed to any other process.)

Generally speaking, you can use `sudo -S` to make `sudo` expect the password on stdin. But also generally speaking, if you have to hardcode a password in a script, you're doing it wrong in some way.

Answer (score 2):

> Is there anyway to have the script enter the password

Putting password in script is not a good idea. First, from security point of view, password may be recovered from script from anyone with access to script. Second, from maintenance view, once you change your password, scripts suddenly stop working and you have to update them all.

Fortunately, as you are already using `sudo` there is better solution. You can configure `sudo` to allow running certain command without password, by using `NOPASSWD` rule in `/etc/sudoers`.

```
myuser ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: service network-manager restart
```

See:

- [How do I run specific sudo commands without a password?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/159007/how-do-i-run-specific-sudo-commands-without-a-password)
- [How to run a specific program as root without a password prompt?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/18830/how-to-run-a-specific-program-as-root-without-a-password-prompt)

**Warning:** Always edit `/etc/sudoers` with `visudo`, never directly. It prevents you from breaking `/etc/sudoers`. Once you break your `/etc/sudoers`, you won't be able to use `sudo`, including using `sudo` to fix `/etc/sudoers`.

Answer (score 0):

try this /bin/echo -e "password\n" | sudo apt-get update

or see this [Use sudo with password as parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11955298/use-sudo-with-password-as-parameter)

Comment: Just as warning for those who don't follow your link, `ps` is capable of displaying entire command lines.  This means that anyone logged into the computer, remote or local, can run `ps` and see this password.