# Jenkins running tomcat8 sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified with NOPASSWD

Tags: tomcat, jenkins, sudo, sudoers

Trying to execute a `sudo` command from my Jenkins executor, I get the title error.

On the host machine(executor) I have configured the `sudoers` file to contain this line: `jenkins ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL` at the very end.

The command which I am trying to run is `sudo service tomcat8 restart`.

Checking the available answers I got all I need or am I missing something?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29685946/947526

Comment: sudo: 1 incorrect password attempt

Comment: There might be an issue with your sudo setup. Did you use visudo? Does the same setup work for other users? Can you give it a try manually?

Comment: Running the same command directly from the machine as the Jenkins user work without prompting for any pwd...

Answer (score 0):

There might be a workaround: As [Barmar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1491895/barmar) pointed out in a comment to the post "[Use sudo without password INSIDE a script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25215604/)", it is possible to allow a dedicated script be executed by a sudoer. Assume you have a line

```
 jenkins ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:/path/to/restart.sh
```

this means that Jenkins can do sudo `/path/to/restart.sh` without a password.

If you now put your command `service tomcat8 restart` in `restart.sh`, a `sudo /path/to/restart.sh` should do the job.

Answer (score 0):

Try turning off `requiretty` for the jenkins user. I would recommend using [command aliases](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Sudoers#Command_Aliases) in your sudoers file as well.

```
Cmnd_Alias RESTART_TOMCAT = /sbin/service tomcat8 *, /etc/init.d/tomcat8 *

Defaults:jenkins !requiretty

jenkins  ALL=(root) NOPASSWD: RESTART_TOMCAT
```