# PHP shell_exec does not work for some commands?

Tags: php, shell

If I do the following command, I get an 'hey' output:

```
echo shell_exec("echo 'hey'");
```

But If I do the following command, it will not kill any `screen`:

```
echo shell_exec("killall screen");
```

Or if I do

```
echo shell_exec("sh /var/www/html/run.sh");
```

It will not run that file at all ***(that file does the screen killing aswell)***

And If I even get that file with get contents, it successfully reads the content in it.

If it can execute `echo` so whats wrong?

Comment: It's probably permissions. `killall` usually needs su/sudo permission, if it's not your own process.

Comment: Most likely the user your website runs as does not have permission to execute `kill` and similar commands.

Comment: Is giving the permission something PHP sided, or server?

Comment: There's a good reason for this type of protection...try to imagine how catastrophic it would be to let any user run any command in a shared hosting environment: "Today i feel like taking a break..." `shell_exec("poweroff")` ;)

Comment: @Mikk3lRo I know it's risky, but I am wondering how can I whitelist some commands

Comment: Is it your own machine (ie. do you have root access)? And where are you trying to run it from (I'm guessin apache)?

Comment: @Mikk3lRo Yes. All i want to do is killall screen, killall java, and create a new screen & run a jar in that screen

Comment: or in short... sh run.sh

Comment: You can try to use `exec` function to investigate this problem. `shell_exec` does not show you command return code, but `exec` does.

Comment: Why don't you kill the specific process rather than killall?  Killall shouldn't be used like that, store the PID of the process you are wanting to manage somewhere.

Comment: I first test killall to see if  it worsk at all

Comment: There may be a way to have `run.sh` run a command within the script as an authenticated user without giving your web user any permissions or other access to the system.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25215604/use-sudo-without-password-inside-a-script  -- this might be helpful

Answer (score 0):

To run such powerful commands, I had to use [this library](http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/) as stated in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6270419/how-to-execute-ssh-commands-via-php). This allows me to login into the SSH with root access and execute any command!

```
function ssh_script($script, $ip, $user, $pass) {
            $ssh = new Net_SSH2($ip);
    if (!$ssh->login($user, $pass)) {
        exit('Login Failed');
    }

    if ($ssh !== false) {
        echo $ssh->exec("sh " . $script);
    }
    else {
        echo "fail";
    }
}
```