# Escaping a " inside a system() call for use in echo command

Tags: c, shell, raspberry-pi

The problem is as follows:

I have a task to write a driver for a quartz clock on a *Raspberry Pi*, the driver should allow concurrent access for reading/writing. Therefore I used semaphores to block access.

Now I want to test this, therefore I have to run

```
sudo hwclock -r -f ...
```

My idea was to write a program in C to make this test automatic, and use fork to run access concurrently. But I cannot run the program as superuser since I don't have those permissions on the *Pi*.

What I tried to do was:

```
system("echo pass\"word | sudo -S hwclock --set --date \"7/20/37 12:00:00\" -f /dev/<device>");
```

and

```
system("echo pass\x22word | sudo -S hwclock --set --date \"7/20/37 12:00:00\" -f /dev/<device>");
```

both give me the error

```
sh: 1: Syntax error: Unterminated quoated string
```

Running the program with **"password"** instead of **"pass\"word"** works without the error.

So what I need is some way to let the program **"enter"** the password for me.

Hopefully, someone can help me with this or point me in the right direction.
Other ways to accomplish testing this are appreciated.

Comment: Configure sudo so you don't need a password.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25215604/use-sudo-without-password-inside-a-script  Are you really planning on hardcoding your password into your source code?!?!  You've already broadcast to quite an audience that your password has a `"` character in it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With `"pass\"word"` you only escape the double-quote for the C string, it's still not escaped in the shell. That means you try to execute `echo pass"word`, which indeed is an unterminated string.

You need to escape the double-quote in the shell-command being executed as well, as in `"pass\\\"word"`. That will be the command `echo pass\"word` in the shell.

Comment: Or use `"echo 'pass\"word' ...`