# How to run command as another user

Tags: bash, sudo

I have a shell script that makes a few calls to Asterisk at some point and shows some output. Calling Asterisk is the first thing I have tried that seems *not* to work. I determined the user I setup to run the script didn't have the permissions to run Asterisk, so I looked at ways to run it as root which would get around that (the only other user on the system).

I tried using `su` with no luck. For the past two hours, I've been messing with `sudo` and `sudoers` and not been able to get it working.

For example, here is some code called in my script, run by the user `com`:

```
printf "\n"
calls=`sudo "asterisk -rx 'core show channels'" | grep "active call"`
lastinboundcaller=`cat /var/log/asterisk/lastcaller.txt`
printf '%s\n' "Current Call Count: $calls"
printf '%s\n' "Last Inbound Caller: $lastinboundcaller"
```

Output:

```
[sudo] password for com:
sudo: asterisk -rx 'core show channels': command not found
Current Call Count:
Last Inbound Caller: Unknown
```

There are two problems here,

1. It's prompting for a password. Why it's prompting for the *current* user's password rather than the root password, I have no idea, but it shouldn't prompt for any password at all.
2. The Asterisk command `asterisk -rx "command"` is still not working — in other words, it's still failing to run the Asterisk shell, though it should have permission.

I tried updating my `sudoers` file and creating a new file in `/etc/sudoers.d` titled `asterisk` as well and putting my command in there.

My latest modification to that file was:

```
com ALL = (ALL:ALL) NOPASSWD: /usr/sbin/asterisk
```

Before that, I tried:

```
com ALL = (root) NOPASSWD: /usr/sbin/asterisk
```

My understanding is this *should* allow the user `com` to execute asterisk as sudo *without* a password. Clearly, something is not working.

I have followed the answers to numerous similar SO posts, like:

- [Use sudo without password INSIDE a script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25215604/use-sudo-without-password-inside-a-script)
- https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/18877/what-is-the-proper-sudoers-syntax-to-add-a-user

Unfortunately, despite following all the answers I've been able to find on this issue, none have worked for me.

Can anyone point me in the right direction here or suggest an alternative? I already consulted a Linux expert and this seems to be the right approach. This is all super easy to do in Windows and I'm surprised it's all this convoluted in Linux.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't quote the argument to `sudo`. It expects the first argument to be the name of the command, so it thinks the whole command line is the program name.

It should be

```
calls=`sudo asterisk -rx 'core show channels' | grep "active call"`
```

> Why it's prompting for the current user's password rather than the root password, I have no idea, but it shouldn't prompt for any password at all.

That's how `sudo` works. It prompts for the current user's password, and checks `/etc/sudoers` to see if they're allowed to run the command. You're thinking of `su`, which prompts for the root password.

Comment: Your solution just worked for me, but will it still prompt for the current password again in the future? I don't want it to do that, either.

Comment: The `NOPASSWD` setting in `/etc/sudoers` should prevent that.

Comment: Gotcha, but then why was it prompting for the password even with NOPASSWD set?